# Can we implement interface for react state attributes in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have following code

```
interface inputElementProperties {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
        Type: "text",
        placeholder: "",
    },
    value: "",
    validations: {
        maxLength: 100,
    },
    valid: true,
    touched: false,
    shouldValidate: false
}


class Home extends React.Component<inputElementProperties>{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardOne: {
                Company: inputElementProperties{
                    elementType: "input",
                    elementConfig: {
                        Type: "checkbox",
                        placeholder: "",
                    },
                    value: "",
                    shouldValidate: false,
                    touched: false,
                    valid:true
                },
                Prefix: {
                    elementType: "input",
                    elementConfig: {
                        Type: "text",
                        placeholder: "",
                    },
                    value: "",
                    validations: {
                        maxLength: 10,
                    },
                    valid: true,
                    touched: false,
                    shouldValidate: true
                }
            }
       }
}
```

I want to implement inputElementProperties to each attribute of cardOne property in state.

Getting errors such as : inputElementProperties refers to a type but being used as a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface Props {
  // ...
}

interface State {
  // HERE YOU CAN USE THE Props INTERFACE
  // IF THAT IS WHAT YOU NEED
}


class Home extends React.Component<Props,State> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state;     // THIS SHOULD BE TYPE State
        this.props;     // THIS SHOULD BE TYPE Props
    }
}
```

You can also check more details on this example: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kenyg?file=/src/index.tsx)